# How to connect to my ASP.NET MVC WEB API from android app

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and a UsersController in it with get, put, update and delete.
In order to call it from my internet browser I call:

```
http://localhost:46040/api/users
```

and receive list of all users in xml format.

I am trying for days to access it from my android application with a simple get users, without any luck.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. To what IP do I call when running in debug from the device?
3. How do I activate the "api/users"?

Here is my server UsersController Get code:

```
public IEnumerable<UserModel> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<User> query;
        IEnumerable<UserModel> results;

        try
        {
            query = TheRepository.GetAllUsers();
            results = query.ToList().Select(s => TheModelFactory.CreateModel(s));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception has been caught: " + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Here is my android code attempt:

```
//private final String url = "http://localhost:46040/Api/Users";//tried this from emulator and device, does not work

private final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:46040/Api/Users";//tried this from emulator, does not work
public void GetAllUsers()
{

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse resp = null;

            try {

                resp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
                String content = entity.getContent().toString();
                Log.e("content", content);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    };

    t.start();

}
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: ksoap2 is for Soap webaervice.................

Comment: Thanks, my web service is RESTful API though..